# PHP index array to associative first element equals second and so on

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this :

```
$actions = array(
   "controller",
   "index",
   "method",
   "default",
);
```

I want to get the first key equals the second key and so on like this

```
$actions = array(
  "controller" => "index",
  "method" => "default"
);
```

How can i do this thanks !!

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: loop through your array using for loop check out for loops here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with for loop:-

```
<?php

$actions = array(
   "controller",
   "index",
   "method",
   "default",
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($actions); $i++)
{
   $arr[$actions[$i]] = $actions[$i += 1];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```